# neo4j can't see database from terminal

Tags: neo4j, cypher-shell

this might be a stupid question but I'm new to neo4j.
I'm using the desktop version and from there I created a new database from a new project. I also can see it from the browser and I can see data and stuff.

[image]
But if I go on my terminal and run

```
cypher-shell
```

and from there I type

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

I can only see the default dbs:
[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: check to make sure the port is correct when connecting.  See `cypher-shell -h` and notice the standard port is `neo4j://localhost:7687` however my AppImage for the desktop switched this at setup to `neo4j://localhost:7688`.  When I use `cypher-shell -a 'neo4j://localhost:7688'` I can see all my databases

Answer (score 0):

From the Neo4j desktop, you'll see the Start/Stop and Open buttons for a project database. Just to the right of these are 3-dots. Click on that and then open folder. This will get you to the various folders for the database. It's useful for seeing the size of the database, working with the config file, managing transaction logs, etc.

Comment: Yes I know, but what I mean is that if I go on terminal and run cypher-shell, I cannot see the databases I created via desktop. I don't understand how to do it